# I can't disable "dealnloot" site push notifications in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I'm unable to turn off a site's notification in windows 10, it keeps popping up now and then. It appears as 
[in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62PiS.jpg).
I allowed this site to show me windows notifications when windows 10 asked me to do, but I can't see this app in "notifications and actions" settings, even when I turn off "Show app notifications" it keeps popping up.
I tried to search for the site name in windows registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/PushNotifications), no luck there too. I just can't figure out how to shut it.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for browser and Windows Explorer add-ins. Many anti-malware products, such as Avast! free, can do that for you. Also check what processes are running, using Task Manager, and kill any from DealInLoot;uninstall them in *Programs and Features*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click on the notification and chose "disable notification from dealnloot". 
Else, go to Chrome settings, search for notification settings and disable the dealnloot notification. Hope this helps.